# How to create multiline legend in teechart?

Tags: legend, multiline, teechart

Does anybody know if there a way to write multiline legend of a chart?
I've tried to add TeeLineSeparator or #13, and it doesn't work?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not in the current legend. The alternatives are to use the CustomLegend tool TeeChart Pro provides or to directly draw your shapes and strings in the `OnAfterDraw` event using custom drawing techniques. Ie:

```
uses Series, TeCanvas;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
  Chart1.Legend.Visible:=false;
  Chart1.MarginRight:=22;

  for i:=0 to 4 do
    with Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries) as TBarSeries do
    begin
      Title:='Long title in Series number ' + IntToStr(i);
      FillSampleValues;
      Marks.Visible:=false;
      MultiBar:=mbStacked;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Chart1AfterDraw(Sender: TObject);
var tmpHeight, i: Integer;
begin
  tmpHeight:=Chart1.SeriesCount*33;

  with Chart1.Canvas do
  begin
    Rectangle(Chart1.Width-130, 50, Chart1.Width-10, 50+tmpHeight);

    for i:=0 to Chart1.SeriesCount-1 do
    begin
      Brush.Color:=Chart1[i].Color;
      Rectangle(Chart1.Width-120, 65+i*30, Chart1.Width-120+15, 65+i*30+15);

      TextOut(Chart1.Width-100, 60+i*30, WrapText(Chart1[i].Title, #13#10, ['.',' ',#9,'-'], 15));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

[image: legend manually drawn]